# Sending Data to Bluetooth Weighing Scale

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to send the data from android device to bluetooth weighing scale.I am able to successfully read the data from the bluetooth scale. But I am not sure if the weighing scale is able to receive the data that i send.Below is the code that i have used:

```
  public void setup() {
        Button btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(etMessage.getText().length() != 0) {
                    bt.send(etMessage.getText().toString(), true);
                    etMessage.setText("");
                }
            }
   });
```

When I click send button , I am not to view anything. 
Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: What kind of BT you use?

Comment: It's just a normal BT. Didnt use any GATT profiles.

Comment: Is your wight has some open API?  Are you sure that  that your request is can be processing on weight side?

Comment: The weighing machine doesn't seem to have any API. Is there anything that i need to configure on weight side?? If so, pls suggest some ideas.

Comment: Only one way: revers engineering
Get firmware from MCU which control BT. If info from socket can't be processing, u don't get any feedback from device. If device MCU is wide known you can write your own firmware for it where your socket connection via BT will be processed.

Comment: Will try that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I can give recommendation: take some Arduino board and BT module and try to construct simple device, its not expensive, but give you understanding how it work, how it can  be work and how crack it